# Short story about a young man who comes of age in a world where everyone gets a trade downloaded into their brain

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, brain-implant

However, they say he is not suitable, so they send him to a college where he has to learn by reading. He breaks out and tries to convince the spacers that they can save loads of money by training themselves and not buying the downloads. He comes back to find out that he is one of the clever ones, as they need people to learn so they can build the downloads.

Comment: Agree with Andrew, it's *definitely* "[Profession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profession_(short_story))"

Comment: Thank you so much, I’m an Asimov fan but just could not remember where I read it ;-)))

Comment: Hi Bill and welcome to the SFF SE :-) Thanks for confirming this is _Profession_. I've linked it to the first question about the story. Many Asimov stories have been asked about multiple times as we all love Asimov's stories! :-)